# How to populate a text field with double quotes using field calculator

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator

How would I populate a text field with double quotes using the Field Calculator.  For example, I want to populate a field as 24".  Is there a way to populate fields using the field calculator with this value?  If I use "24"", I get an error because of the two double quotes.

Comment: Found the answer... "24\"" ... need to escape out the double quote.

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies, didn't know you could use single quotes with python, easy solution!

Comment: In the VB parser it's "24""" that's "" to insert a " and " to finish so 3x". Another option is chr(42) where 42 is the ASCII code for " so "24" & chr(42)

Answer (score 4):

Change the parser to Python using the radio button at the top of the field calculator window, then use single-quotes to enclose your text:

```
'24"'
```

Python allows you to use either single- or double-quotes to enclose a string. If you wanted to use an apostrophe in your text field, you would use double-quotes instead:

```
"Owner's"
```

Answer (score 3):

with python, you can use either " " or ' ' to identify your text

so you could do it like this :

'24"'

but the best method if you don't want to play with \' and \" when you have both ' and " in your string, is to use the triple """

""" 24's"  """